# bash SED command explanation with semicolon

Tags: sed

What is this sed command doing? and is there any online utility that kind of explains sed a little bit, like regex?

```
sed -i '1s/$/|,a Type,b Type,c Type/;/./!b;1!s/$/|,,,/' textflile.txt
```

I think in the beginning it is adding csv a type, b type, c type at the end of the line but what does the rest of the command too

Comment: And this is why I always say `sed is for s/old/new, that is all`. Do anything else with sed and you get a cryptic incantation like this that usually not even the author understands a month later and no-one can build upon when requirements change. Post some sample input and the output you get after running that and I expect someone can show you how to do the same with a clear, simple, portable, efficient awk script.

Comment: [This](http://tpcg.io/lulMGQ) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any such utility, but let me explain using a text editor:

```
sed -i '1s/$/|,a Type,b Type,c Type/;/./!b;1!s/$/|,,,/' textflile.txt
    ^   ^  ^                          ^ ^^ ^^                       ^
    |   |  |                          | || ||                       |
modify  |  End                Non-empty || ||                       input
the     |  of                 lines     || |Negation,               file
file    |  line               only      || |i.e. lines 2,3,...
in      |                               || |
place   |                               || First
     First line            Negation, i.e.| line
                         empty lines only|
                                         Branch to
                                         script end,
                                         i.e. skip the rest
```

In other words, it adds `|,a type, b Type,c Type` to the first line, doesn't change empty lines, and adds `|,,,` to all the remaining lines.

Comment: What does that actually DO though?

Comment: @EdMorton: Updated.

Comment: Wow. Such a complicated script for such a simple task. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i '1s/$/|,a Type,b Type,c Type/;/./!b;1!s/$/|,,,/' textflile.txt
```

can be written as

```
sed -i '
    1 s/$/|,a Type,b Type,c Type/
    /./! b
    1! s/$/|,,,/
' textflile.txt
```

1. on line 1 only, add some text to the end of the line
2. if the line is empty ("matches 1 character, not"), goto next "cycle" (i.e., print current line and go to next line)
3. on every line *except line 1*, add "|,,," to the end of the line

So, it looks like you're adding some blank fields to a CSV file.

`info sed` contains the complete sed manual.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question but it's important for people to know and requires more space and formatting than a comment so: FYI to do what [@choroba says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52540671/1745001) that sed script does, i.e.

```
it adds |,a type, b Type,c Type to the first line,
doesn't change empty lines,
and adds |,,, to all the remaining lines.
```

is just this in awk:

```
awk '
    NR==1 { print $0 "|,a type, b Type,c Type"; next }
    !NF   { print }
    NF    { print $0 "|,,," }
'
```

or if you're familiar with ternary expressions and want to remove the redundant code:

```
awk '{
    sfx = "|," (NR==1 ? "a type, b Type,c Type" : ",,")
    print $0 (NF ? sfx : "")
}'
```